# limitation of pyspark partitions successfully written to aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I have Pyspark running in Jupyter Notebook in Kube cluster.
Everything is working, I can write/read to/from `AWS S3`/`Postgres`, use `pyspark.sql` etc.

And I can write partitions to S3, but only if the number of partitions doesn't exceed 17:

```
partitions = test.repartition(17)
```

then I write

```
partitions.write.parquet('s3a://' + s3_bucket + '/folder',mode="overwrite")
```

and I see how files start to appear in my `S3` folder, first at `folder/temporary/0`, but after it all written I see in my `folder`:
`_SUCCESS`
and all partitions starting with `part-00000` and ending with `part-00016`

But if I do

```
partitions = test.repartition(20)
```

then again I see all files (20) appear in `folder/temporary/0`, I see in Spark UI `20 Completed tasks` all with `SUCCESS` label.
but at the end at `S3`
I'm only getting 17 files in `folder` without `_SUCCESS` file and in my Jupyter Notebook I'm getting

```
Job aborted
...
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: ..., AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: ...
```

I was trying big and small files, checked memory of executors, but can't get more than 17 partitions.
I have

`Spark 2.4.5`
`Python 3.7`
`aws-java-sdk:1.7.4`
`hadoop-aws:2.7.3`
`postgresql-42.2.14`
`datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6`

I'm logging to `S3` with `IAM` role (tried with key/secret - didn't change anything).

I don't have problem with connecting/writing/reading to/from `S3`, I have a problem of writing more than 17 partitions to `S3`

I also tried to increase the number of pods and cores from 2 workers and 1 core up to 6 workers and 2 cores, didn't change anything with this error.

Thank you!

Comment: What are the number of pods you are using, just want to ask

Comment: I tried different number of pods and cores. Started with 1 driver and 2 workers and 1 core, changed to 6 workers and also 2 cores, didn't change anything. I have it running in kube cluster, memory was not a problem.